# CSS3 Animations Error

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a Loading Circle that bounces using CSS3 Animations. I have writen a simple fade out animation in CSS that hides the progress circle after a certain amount of seconds, but it does not seem to be working.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Lc489/5)

Comment: Which browser are you running it in?

Comment: Start by replacing `@keyframes` with `@-moz-keyframes`. It looks like you bound to the first animation but not the second.

Comment: Are you able to use any external libraries or scripts like _animate.css_ (http://daneden.me/animate/)?

Comment: `animation:` should be `-moz-animation:`.

Comment: Start with something [working](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc489/15/) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing browser prefixes, which are currently required for CSS animation to work in major browsers.

The prefix for Firefox and other Mozilla browsers is `-moz-`, WebKit is `-webkit-`, Opera is `-o-`, and IE is `-ms-`.

Alternatively you can try the minuscule, 2kb JavaScript which is [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/). The script is tiny, and, if nothing else, it'll save you some time and trouble, as you won't have to type all those prefixes.